# How Does a Service Worker Know to Update?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, caching, amazon-cloudfront, service-worker

I'm trying to build a service worker in React to detect changes in an S3 bucket that's being hosted via Cloudfront, but I can only get the update function to trigger when the page reloads. I guess I don't really understand *how* the service worker knows to update things. I did disable all cache in Cloudfront to make sure there wasn't a conflict of some sort as well. I've followed countless tutorials and I've basically resorted to even copying and pasting the extremely common code you find on all tutorials, but with the same result. I've also viewed many articles on the lifecycle, but I still just don't understand *how* it knows there's an update. I'm currently using this example: https://deanhume.com/displaying-a-new-version-available-progressive-web-app/

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to update the app or do you want to detect changed on a bucket? Or your app is hosted on that bucket?

Comment: So I have the app's code in the S3 bucket but it's served over Cloudfront. I'm wanting the service worker to detect when files have changed in the bucket and/or have been updated (I clear the bucket first and then re-upload everything) so theoretically I would think that it would detect that the files have been updated due to the upload timestamp being different. From there I'd do whatever but the main problem is just detecting newer files in the S3 bucket.

Comment: Update: i tried just uploading a new file instead of clearing the bucket and updating, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help, I've been looking into it for some time. On Angular, there is a json file (ngsw.json) that contains a hash table, this table looks like this:

```
"hashTable": {
    "/index.html": "4f5c690352e4a44a0e4477aecdd8e1a8cc5ff6cf",
    "/main.daf1c14bd2840a967b00.js": "3c430c33be512e07a2be37546ba347d6a4ca7f52",
    "/polyfills.02f925d581acabc054de.js": "0baf1f319c628f0e0241fe2255b01713da669b06",
    "/runtime.423876bdf008fc4fd61e.js": "e34e25e3c24c465898be3ca59ffbcad2ca31e9cf",
    "/styles.d30753183b32d43cebfa.css": "a27cde0231bba0947197999242cc83d826f6fa1f"
  },
```

From memory, the files contained within this hash table are the files that are triggering the update. An update is triggered once a hash has changed.
In some preferences files, I kind of remember that I was able to specify which files should trigger an update.
I am sorry I can't be more precise, but hopefully it will help you!